# Prevent simultaneous opening of a sheet by multiple people

Tags: excel, vba

My colleagues and I need to work on one Excel sheet "Sheet", but never at the same time (we don`t use Office 365 for several reasons).

To avoid two people working on the document at the same time, I have written a macro.

It prevents the workbook being opened by more than one person at the same time and provides a note via a MsgBox "File is already open".

However, if the user has another workbook open and then closes "Sheet", "Sheet" reopens again and again with the note that it is already open.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim vSperrFile As String
    Dim vDNr As Integer
    Dim vZeit As String
    Dim vSperrFileExists As Boolean

    vSperrFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sperre.txt"
    vDNr = FreeFile

    On Error Resume Next
    Open vSperrFile For Input As vDNr
    vSperrFileExists = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0

    If vSperrFileExists Then
        Input #vDNr, vZeit 'Zeit einlesen, bis zu der die Datei gesperrt ist
        Close vDNr
        If CDate(vZeit) > Now Then 'wenn die Sperrzeit noch nicht erreicht ist,
            'Datei schließen
            'MsgBox "Gesperrt!"
            MsgBox "Datei in Bearbeitung durch anderen MA!"
            ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If        
    End If

    'Datei sperren, falls Sperrdatei nicht existiert oder Sperrzeit abgelaufen
    Call Sperren

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a macro for that? 
You may use the "shared workbooks" feature, which is a old method but it is still allowed. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534?ns=excel&version=90&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: Thanks @FernandoBarbosa for this idea. But how do I secure that no one can save edits, while another person also did some edits and then some edits are lost?

Comment: If you're not using Office 365 then isn't the file locked when the first person opens it?